# How to understand a sentence about "reload" function in official documents

Tags: python, reload

According to to document of "reload" function in Python,there is a sentence ,

"When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, the old definition remains. **This feature can be used to the module’s advantage if it maintains a global table or cache of objects — with a try statement it can test for the table’s presence and skip its initialization if desired**:"

and give a excample as below:

```
try:
    cache
except NameError:
    cache = {}
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

I can't understand the sentence with boldface and the code above. Anyone can explain it for me ? And better to show me a simple excample.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! I'm curious--why are you calling [reload()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)? What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: @Robᵩ Sorry for my late response, because I would like to achieve  something like hot-fix , but "reload" function cannot meet the need in some aspect.